# Redirecting with .htaccess to external domain

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to figure out how I can redirect with .htaccess to external domains. Basically this is the redirect I want to do.

Redirecting: `http://www.domain.eu/nl` to `http://www.domain.nl/nl`. But also I want to redirect deeper links with certain sub-directories.

Redirecting: `http://www.domain.eu/nl/news/100-article-with-a-name/` to `http://www.domain.nl/nl/news/100-article-with-a-name/`

Can anyone help me figuring out how to do this? Or does anyone have a key tip to help me?
Both domains are running Joomla 3.x installations.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect main domain and all pages to other domain using below .htaccess code :

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please ask if you have any query.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input.
I'm trying to rewrite every url that has domain.eu/nl/some-category/some-article to domain.nl/nl/some-category/some-article.

I figured the above out as well. Unfortunately I do not find how to redirect from deeper articles / directories yet. Could you give me a tip? :)

Comment: Did you try my given code? it will work for base  and all sub pages URL.

Comment: These two lines don't solve it, just redirects to the other domain, doesn't include the sub page paths.

Comment: I think you will get solution here : https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/nl/(.*)$`
`RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.nl/nl/%1 [R=303,NC]`

This still redirects wrong whenever I for instance try it to redirect `http://www.domain.eu/nl/contact` to `http://www.domain.nl/nl/contact`